# Split a string into multiple rows and get the count for each of them

Tags: ms-access

I have a table "Production Database" in Server. I am using MS Access as a front end interface. I have some forms there. I want to create a query which will split records in "Reviewer" column and give me count for each of them. below is an example of the column, how it looks like

```
Reviewer
-----------------------
Person1,Person2,Person5 
Person3,Person1
Person4
```

Please help. Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi and welcome to the forum. Please tag your SQL-Server version.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the forum! Maybe you could consider changing your schema?

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like this if you have a recent version of SQL Server! I've used PostgreSQL for this example - but SQL Server has the [`STRING_SPLIT`](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4884/sql-server-2016-stringsplit-function/) function which appears to be very similar to PostgreSQL's [`regexp_split_to_table`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/functions-string.html) function.

I can't appear to get SQL Server's  function to [`work`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=690e937bf34b3b99920eb6de5d444453) on [dbfiddle.uk](https://dbfiddle.uk/) (Express Edition issue?). My own dbfiddle of the code below can be found [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=5466cb761fec686f5bf363905d07ef42)! There's also an SQL Server [`UNNEST`](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-e&q=sql%20server%20unnest%20array) function but the second SQL doesn't appear to be as compatible!

Create and populate your table -

```
CREATE TABLE reviewer(
Reviewer TEXT
);
```

data -

```
INSERT INTO reviewer
        ( Reviewer )
VALUES ('Person1,Person2,Person5') 
,('Person3,Person1')
,('Person4');
```

and then run this SQL (suitably translated for SQL Server) -

```
SELECT rev, COUNT(rev) 
FROM
(
  SELECT regexp_split_to_table(r.reviewer, ',') AS rev -- use STRING_SPLIT here!
  FROM reviewer r
) AS tab
GROUP BY rev
ORDER BY rev
```

Result -

```
Rev     count
Person1     2
Person2     1
Person3     1
Person4     1
Person5     1
```

You should always include your version of SQL Server when asking questions here. p.s. welcome to the forum!

You could also try something like this - but it would appear to be more difficult to translate the SQL - just an FYI - same result!

```
SELECT rev, COUNT(rev)
FROM
(
  SELECT rev
  FROM reviewer r,
  unnest(string_to_array(r.reviewer, ',')) AS rev
) AS tab
GROUP BY rev
ORDER BY rev
```

Answer (score 1):

First create a splitting function that will get string and delimiter and will return a table.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_Split] ( @StringInput VARCHAR(8000), @Delimiter nvarchar(10))
RETURNS @OutputTable TABLE ( [String] VARCHAR(8000))
AS
BEGIN
    SET @Delimiter = LTRIM(RTRIM(@Delimiter))
    DECLARE @String    VARCHAR(10)

    WHILE LEN(@StringInput) > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @String      = LEFT(@StringInput, 
                                ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @StringInput) - 1, -1),
                                LEN(@StringInput)))
        SET @StringInput = SUBSTRING(@StringInput,
                                     ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @StringInput), 0),
                                     LEN(@StringInput)) + 1, LEN(@StringInput))

        INSERT INTO @OutputTable ( [String] )
        VALUES ( @String )
    END

    RETURN
END
```

Then get the expected result using `CROSS APPLY` as follows.

```
CREATE TABLE #reviewer(
Reviewer VARCHAR(100)
)
GO

INSERT INTO #reviewer
        ( Reviewer )
VALUES ('Person1,Person2,Person5') 
,('Person3,Person1')
,('Person4')

SELECT spl.String, COUNT(*)
FROM #reviewer
CROSS APPLY dbo.fn_Split(Reviewer, ',') spl
GROUP BY spl.String
```

Comment: If OP is running SQL-Server 2016 or above maybe it is more suitable to use the integrated STRING_SPLIT function.

Comment: Thank you @Artashes. I am very new to SQL. Could you please help me with this step by step. I want to add this to MS Access so where do I paste this code? to VBA or SQL Query? Also, the combination of Persons will be different and number of Persons will be different. So will the second part work?

Comment: @BirajDeb The provided solution is for MS SQL Server as you mentioned in tag of your question.

Comment: Thank you. I thought I could get a solution for MS Access. Thanks for your support